# writing bulk data to big Query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I would like to write the bulk data to BQ using software API.

My restrictions are:

- I am going to use the max size of BQ, columns 10,000  and ~35000 rows (this can be bigger)
- Schema autodetect is required
- If possible, I would like to use some kind of parallelism to write many tables at the same time asynchronously (for that Apache-beam & dataflow might be the solution)
- When using Pandas library for BQ, there is a limit on the size of the dataframe that can be written. this requires partitioning of the data

What would be the best way to do so?

Many thanks for any advice / comment,
eilalan

Answer (score 0):

Apache beam would be the right component as it supports huge volume data processing in batch and streaming mode.

I don't think Beam as "Schema auto-detect". But, you can use BigQuery API to fetch the schema if the table already exists.